# Multiple value for a key in HashMap in java

Tags: java

#### Problem

I am struggling to solve a problem where user inputs student name with marks i.e [(John,50),(Allex,70),(Tim,80),(Allex,90)].

Now I want average of marks of each student i.e [(John,50),(Allex,80),(Tim,80)].

As I was planning to use HashMap in this case but I realized that a single key cannot have multiple values so how can I approach the question using map or another data structure.

Comment: Store a list of values per key, e.g. `Map<String, List<Integer>>`

Comment: Or use a Multimap: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#multimaps

Comment: Don't use a `Map` - you are basically abusing a `Map` as a pair of parallel arrays. Use a `List<Student>`, or even better a `Set<Student>`. If you really want to use a `Map` consider `map.merge("Alex", 90, Integer::sum)`.

Comment: You don't need to store multiple values in order to compute an average. All you need is a single object per student, containing the sum of his marks and the total number of marks for that student. The average is the division of the sum by the total.

Comment: Or, use a [moving average](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/106720).

Answer (score 1):

Single Key cannot have multiple values but single key can have a single object capable of holding multiple value!
Use

```
HashMap<String, List<Integer>>
```

Or you can also use

```
HashMap<String,List<subject>>
```

where subject class can have subject name,subject id,etc...

Comment: `s/<subject>/<Subject>/g`.

Comment: Also, there's nothing wrong with storing a moving average as an integer in the `Map`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider how can you compute a moving average with just an integer? You'd need the moving sum, and the moving total of marks.

Comment: @JBNizet you'd need to store the number of observations and the current average, true - but from that you can compute the next iteration.